# the questions about scanf() and cin

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

I met a questions. the link ->
[the problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1633/C)
here is my solution.If i use `scanf`, the code can be accepted on codeforces, but replace `cin` then not,it occurs wrong answer,but in my local interpreter using cin is ok.
why?

```
int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    nt :
    while (t--) {
        long long hc, dc, hm, dm, w, a;
        long k;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld%lld%d%lld%lld", &hc, &dc, &hm, &dm, &k, &w, &a); // ok
//        cin >> hc >> dc >> hm >> dm >> k >> w >> a; // cannot work
        for (int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
            int opt = k - i;
            long long hc1 = opt * a + hc;
            long long dc1 = i * w + dc;
            long long cnt1 = hm / dc1 + (hm % dc1 > 0);
            long long cnt2 = hc1 / dm + (hc1 % dm > 0);
            if (cnt1 <= cnt2) {
                printf("YES\n");
                goto nt;
            }
        }
        printf("NO\n");
    }
}
```

I just try a lot of practices , found the key of question is input of question.

Comment: Have you included iostream?

Comment: If you get an error message, tell us what it is. Don't make us guess. (But first read the message and try to understand what it is telling you.)

Comment: yes, included iostream. My poblem has been solved. Thank you for so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another scanf in line 5 which you have to replace too. Otherwise they each have their own buffers of the input and get mixed up.

Comment: yep,you are right.Thank you for so much